# Jni интерфейсы java

Tags: android, c++, jni, native

Из сторонней библиотеки необходимо вызывать методы в `C++`

`Callback.java`

```
void onFailure(String request, IOException e);
void onResponse(String response) throws IOException;
```

`Utils.java`

```
public class Utils{
public Utils(){
//Какой то код
}

public void enqueue(Callback responseCallback) {
//Какой то код
}
}
```

Вызов в `MainActivity.java`

```
new Utils().enqueue(new Callback() {
@Override
public void onFailure(String request, IOException e) {
    //Какой то код
}

@Override
public void onResponse(String response) throws IOException {
    //Какой то код
}
});
```

`C++`

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_com_nativeutils_nativeutils_MainActivity_test(JNIEnv *env,jobject) {
jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/nativeutils/nativeutils/Utils");
jmethodID mtd = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>","()V");
jobject obj = env->NewObject(cls, mtd);
return NULL;
}
```

На `C++` нужно вызвать метод `enqueue` в который передать `Callback` для получения результата.Другими словами переделать вызов метода из `MainActivity.java`. Метод вызвать не проблема проблема передать интерфейс в метод.Как это реализовать?

Comment: "проблема передать интерфейс в метод" И откуда его перед этим взять. Какая-то очень странная архитектура. Обычно передают класс с данными, а не кодом - onFailure, onResponse.

Comment: Так и нужно интерфейс с java перенести на c++.Далее вместо интерфейса java вызвать интерфейс c++ в который передать результат работы java метода.В общем калбеки.Из c++ вызываем метод java, а результат передать в c++